# Terraform and AWS secrets

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

I must be missing something in how AWS secrets can be accessed through Terraform. Here is the scenario I am struggling with:

- I create an IAM user named "infra_user", create ID and secret access key for the user, download the values in plain txt.
- "infra_user" will be used to authenticate via terraform to provision resources, lets say an S3 and an EC2 instance.
- To protect the ID and secret key of "infra_user", I store them in AWS secrets manager.
- In order to authenticate with "infra_user" in my terraform script, I will need to retrieve the secrets via the following block:

  ```
   data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "arn" {
    arn = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:example-123456"
  }
  ```

But, to even use the data block in my script and retrieve the secrets wouldn't I need to authenticate to AWS in some other way in my provider block before I declare any resources?
If I create another user, say "tf_user", to just retrieve the secrets where would I store the access key for "tf_user"? How do I avoid this circular authentication loop?

Comment: The environment running the terraform script should take care of calling the terraform script with the right credentials already set. If you run this locally, export the credentials first, if you run this in codebuild it will already have the right credentials, etc. If you run this in github you can also set up the AWS credentials there.

Comment: you need to store your IAM secret in something outside of AWS, because terraform wont be able to access the iam creds secret without iam creds.

Comment: you don't have to store the in a KMS, just use them directly by exporting them as environment variables

Comment: Yes you would need to store the credentials elsewhere. This is known popularly as the "secret zero problem". There are various ways to solve this problem, but we do not know what other tools you have available in your company's ecosystem. If this is executing from an EC2, then you can use an IAM instance profile and be done with the problem immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The Terraform AWS provider documentation has a section on [Authentication and Configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#authentication-and-configuration) and lists an order of precedence for how the provider discovers which credentials to use. You can choose the method that makes the most sense for your use case.

For example, one (insecure) method would be to set the credentials directly in the provider:

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-west-2"
  access_key = "my-access-key"
  secret_key = "my-secret-key"
}
```

Or, you could set the environment variables in your shell:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="my-access-key"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="my-secret-key"
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-west-2"
```

now your provider block simplifies to:

```
provider "aws" {}
```

when you run `terraform` commands it will automatically use the credentials in your environment.

Or as yet another alternative, you can store the credentials in a [profile configuration file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html) and choose which profile to use by setting the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable.

Authentication is somewhat more complex and configurable than it seems at first glance, so I'd encourage you to read the documentation.